# Laravel: How do I create a new row and attach it to my model

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have 2 Models/Tables;

```
Table1Model;
Table2Model;

table_1
table_2
```

Now one Table1Model has one Table2Model, and one Table2Model can be attached to many Table1Model's.

I have the relationship as follows;

In my Table1Model:

```
public function table_2(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Table1Model::class);
}
```

In my Table2Model:

```
public function table_1(){
    return $this->hasMany(Table2Model::class);
}
```

I'm having trouble attaching a Table2Model to a Table1Model (and visa-versa but I wouldn't have too go the other way), the way I am currently doing it is with this method in my Table1Model;

```
public function setTable2($table_2)
{
    $this->table_2_id = ($table_2->id);
    $this->save();
}
```

This just feels a bit clunky, what is the correct way to do it? I got lost in Laravel documentation trying to find out!

Comment: How you are calling `setTable2` and did you tried any code in controller to attach?

Comment: No controllers here bud, just unit testing atm, everything required is in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will enlight how you can take benefit of the relationships.

```
$record = Table2Model::find(1); 
// Returns an ActiveRecord of Table2

dd(record->table_1);
// I think of dd as a friendlier version of var_dump and die
// table_1 being the relationship name, you can see all records that are
// related to that model.
// (you may need to add 'table_1' to $visible property in the Table2Model),
```

You can insert a Table1Model (related to Table2Model), by using the following:

```
$record = Table2Model::find(1);
$record->table_1()->create($arrayOfTable1Data);
```

You may aswell delete all Table1Model records related to Table2Model by doing `->delete()` on the relationship (after you've fetched the ActiveRecord of it)

```
$record = Table2Model::find(1);
$record->table_1()->delete();
```

The other way around, isn't that simple due to the example you provided (Table2Model has many Table1Model, meaning you can't insert a Table1Model without a record of Table2 existing). What you can make, if the foreign_key is nullable, is:

```
$record = Table1Model::create($arrayOfTable1Data);
arrayOfTable1Data['table2_id'] = $record->table_2()->create($arrayOfTable2Data)->id;
$record->table_1()->update($arrayOfTable1Data);
```

Personal note:
I like to give the relationship names the name of the other models and make it singular or plural (e.g. relationship named user or users) depending if it has 1 dependency or has many.

Comment: I feel like a mong now, `$record->table_1()->create($arrayOfTable1Data);` was what I wanted but it completly escaped my memory, nice one!

Answer (score -2):

```
Table1Model::find(1)->table2()->associate(Table2Model::find(1))->save()
Table2Model::find(1)->table1()->save(Table1Model::find(1))
```

You can find mode info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: Yeh I thought there would be a better way, I'll stick to the function I wrote lol

Comment: Yah. Your way is most easy for using. But when using many to many relation you can use `Table1Model::find(1)->table2()->sync([1,2,3])` or ->attach(1)

Comment: Not using many to many and you mixed your answer up btw, it should be `Table1Model::find(1)->table2()->associate(Table2Model::find(1))->save()` if you wanna edit it

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the save. Thanks! Just not using it that way too.